# Program received signal SIGBART when installing app on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, user-interface

I am trying to run the below exmaple on iPhone, but I am getting the error `Program received signal SIGBART when installing app on device`. This is what is on the `RootViewController`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
}
@end
```

And the below in the `.m`-file

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
@implementation RootViewController
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    // [...]
}
```

Here is the error on the console:

```
2012-10-07 22:51:25.319 TestLoopPerformance[1790:207] *** -[UIWindow setRootViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x118f40
2012-10-07 22:51:25.336 TestLoopPerformance[1790:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIWindow setRootViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x118f40'
2012-10-07 22:51:25.346 TestLoopPerformance[1790:207] Stack: (
```

However the code works fine on the simulator but not on device. What can be the problem?

Comment: which iOS version and what kind of device are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setRootViewController:` in `UIWindow` is available since iOS 4.0

If you want to support devices running iOS 3.x you have to change the function which creates the viewController in your AppDelegate... and this will probably not the only change you'll need to make.